# Streaming audio only (.mp3) files using MPEG DASH

Tags: html, google-chrome, mp3, html5-audio, mpeg-dash

Is there any way to stream audio only files (`.mp3`) using `MPEG DASH`. I'm looking at ways to get `HTML5` audio working on chrome without using progressive downloads. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

DASH is both a video delivery system and a video format. It may be possible to have MP3 encoded audio streams in a DASH presentation but they will not be .mp3 files in this case - they will either be `.mp4` or `.ts` files, since those are the two storage formats that DASH supports.

In addition, the support for audio-only adaptive streaming playback is generally very poor. Indeed, even DASH video playback is still spotty in browsers and rife with compatibility problems.

If you wish to successfully use modern adaptive streaming technologies, encode your audio with the much more modern and efficient AAC codec and package it into a proper DASH format.

Comment: How can he packed in proper Dash format(audio or video)?

Comment: He should use a software of course. There are free segmenter around like mp4box, edash. There are also commercial like Evostream and Wowza.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=aac vs http://caniuse.com/#feat=mp3 at the time being mp3 is supported by all but opera mini, while aac support is lacking in Firefox (only if codec present on system level and only in mp4 container). mp3 is the most supported audio format.

Comment: @Sander is this answer still correct, or have there been development that enables to stream audio only using DASH?